# How to pass array of arrays from javascript to a webservice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pcap.net

I have following webservice:

```
[webmethod]
public string MakeReservation(?? PassengersInfo)//what data type use for PassengerInfo 
{
}
```

and in javascript I have following code.

```
 var ResultInfo = new Array();
    $("#GrdPassengerInformationMakeReservation").find('tr:not(:first)').each(function() {
        var Info = new Array();
        Info.push($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
        Info.push(($(this).find('td:eq(2)')).find('select').val());
        Info.push(($(this).find('td:eq(3)')).find('input').val());
        Info.push(($(this).find('td:eq(4)')).find('input').val());
        Info.push(($(this).find('td:eq(5)')).find('select').val());
        Info.push(($(this).find('td:eq(6)')).find('input').val());

        ResultInfo.push(Info);

    })
$.ajax(
    { url: "Ajaxes/Reservation.asmx/MakeReservation",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: "{'PassengersInfo':'" + ResultInfo + "'}",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {

        }
});
```

I want to pass `ResultInfo` to webservice.
What data type should I use in my webservice?

Comment: Please... **NEVER** generate JSON manually with string functions! Simply include https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js and use `JSON.stringify()`!

Comment: Why not? What is it's benefit?

Comment: The same reason why you don't build XML using string functions: You don't want to take care about escaping things, nesting of brackets etc. Besides that, you cannot simply concatenate a string with an array so your code doesn't work while `data: JSON.stringify({PassengersInfo: ResultInfo})` will work like a charm.

Comment: Yes you are right. thanks for your comment.
here is a documentation in msdn. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Info` is an Array, use Array at the server side. But in that case you can pass the `Info` as such instead of sending it inside another array which is again wrapper into an `object` in your ajax post method, i.e. `data: Info`.
Or you can use ArrayList since `ResultInfo` contains arrays (in this case only one array). In that case sent the ajax post with `data: ResultInfo`.

Comment: I used `ArrayList` as `datatype` but in firebug I get following error:
`"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.ArrayList\u0027"`